# Text File won't be created in the SD Card

Tags: java, android, string, file, android-sdcard

I'm trying to create/write to a text file in the SD card root directory on my phone using FileWriter, but the file doesn't get created (/root/sdcard)

Tried using getExternalStorageDirectory() but it just doesn't work. I've also added this to my manifest file outside of the application tag:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Here's my code to write/create the file:

```
private void writeToFile(String content) {
    try {
        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/test.txt");

        if (!file.exists()) {
            file.createNewFile();
        }
        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(file);
        writer.append(content);
        writer.flush();
        writer.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
    }
}
```

I'm expecting a file "test.txt" to be created in the SD card's directory, but nothing happens. No errors either, file just doesn't want to get created.

Comment: micro SD cards are readonly now adays when used in an Android device. getExternalStorageDirectory() has nothing to do with a removable micro SD card. Please tell what you want.

Comment: `file.createNewFile();` Check the return value: `if (! file.createNewFile()){Toast(could not create file..); return false;}`.

Comment: `File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/test.txt");` Better: `File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "test.txt");
`

Comment: `void writeToFile(String content)` Make it return a value: `boolean writeToFile(String content)` and check when called.

Comment: @blackapps Please don't post code in comments. Post it as an Answer, instead.

Comment: Sorry, but those are not answers to the question. Only comments...

Comment: @blackapps You should try to make an answer with those "comments"

Comment: All those comments together dont yet make an answer.  An answer should be a solution for the problem. I have no solution ... yet. I'm waiting for the OP to react.

Comment: "No errors either" -- how would you know? You are ignoring all errors. Add `Log.e("ShorowitzApp", "Exception in file I/O", e);` to your `catch` block, then look at Logcat to see the stack trace. In addition to all of blackapp's comments, note that you do not have access to external or removable storage by default on Android 10+. Please use `ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT` and let the *user* decide where the *user* wants you to put the *user's* data on the *user's* device.

Comment: The error from the exception shows: "Permission denied"

But I've put the permissions in the manifest file. Odd thing is it never asks me to accept them when I open the app though

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by calling the following in the activity onCreate method:

```
    public static void verifyStoragePermissions(Activity activity) {
    // Check if we have write permission
    int permission = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);

    if (permission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // We don't have permission so prompt the user
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                activity,
                PERMISSIONS_STORAGE,
                REQUEST_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
        );
    }
}
```